# Hibernate using a foreign key as part of a composite key

Tags: java, hibernate, foreign-keys, composite-key

Okay, so I have 2 tables on an Oracle DB that I want to represent in Java with Spring 3 and Hibernate 3. They have a Many to One relationship, and the tables are something like

```
 CAR
 -------
 CAR_PK
 //... other columns

 OPTION
 ------
 CAR_FK
 OPTION_TEXT
 //... other columns
```

because the Options table is only meaningful with respect to the Car, we only care about accessing it when the Car is accessed, so it doesn't have a unique PK of its own. Furthermore, there can be more than 1 Option per car. Therefore, we are using a composite id of CAR_FK and OPTIONS_TEXT

the java is something like

```
 public class Car{
    @Id
    @Column(name="CAR_PK")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,  generator="CAR_KEY_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator (name="CAR_KEY_SEQ", sequenceName="CAR_KEY_SEQ", allocationSize=1)
    private long carPk; 

    @OneToMany(cascade= CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="car")
    @JoinColumn(name="CAR_PK")
    private List<Option> options; 

    //... other stuff
 }

 @IdClass(OptionId.class)
 public class Option{

      @Id
      private long carFk; 

      @Id
      private String optionText; 

      @ManyToOne
      @JoinColumn(name="CAR_FK")
      private Car car; 

      //... other stuff
 }


 @Emeddable
 public class OptionId implements Serializable{

      @Column(CAR_FK)
      private long carFk; 
      @Column(OPTION_TEXT)
      private String optionText
      //... other stuff
 }
```

On insert, I want the same key generated for carPk in the Car object to be inserted for carFk in the Option object. How do I do this?I get

```
 java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

First thing is since Option has no existence of its own it should not be an Entity. Only Car is an Entity Object whereas Option is a value Object so it should not have any id of its own.

You could change the design as

```
 @Entity
 public class Car{
    @Id
    @Column(name="CAR_PK")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,  generator="CAR_KEY_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator (name="CAR_KEY_SEQ", sequenceName="CAR_KEY_SEQ", allocationSize=1)
    private long carPk; 

    @Embedded
    private List<Option> options; 

    //... other stuff
 }

@Embeddable
public class Option{
      private String optionText; 

      //... other stuff
 }
```

That should solve all your problems.

Comment: If this solved your problem, accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You do have a typo in your above code when defining your cascade type:

```
@OneToMany(cascase= CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="car")
```

This could be causing your Invalid column index.

Comment: It was just a typo when I transcribed it. Thanks for pointing that out, though. I fixed that typo now.